# How to access UITableView Cell which is not yet in view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to access/update UITableView cell (using reusable cells) which is not in the current view . I know the table view cells are reusable, that can be the reason I am unable to fetch them but is there any way of virtually making and updating. OR I have to drop the reusable cell technique. Suppose tableview have total 20 cells but only say 7 are visible in the current view of iPhone. How will i update other 13 cells which are out of view bounds

Comment: Share the code that you have done then we will be able to help you out...

Comment: Means tableview cell is not in current screen?

Comment: Yes @PayalManiyar ! suppose i have total 20 cells but only say 7 are visible in the current view of iPhone. How will i update other 13 cells which are out of view bounds

Comment: @Divjyot  What is exact requirement?

Comment: But i have seen apps do that! For ex. in whatsapp say user A has cell out of view (scrolled up) and you receive A's message then if you scroll up there is new message and a unread count.. thats pretty much updating the cell which is not in view. refer to this @PayalManiyar

Comment: You don't need to update the cell. You need to update the data source.

Comment: @Divjyot as per seto nugroho  said you have to update data source

Comment: Thanks @PayalManiyar

Answer (score 1):

You can't access those cells because they are not added to the `UITableView` but are kept in a queue until user scrolls to them, then they are added to the `UITableView`. Instead update your model, which will reflect changes on the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing and modifying cells (even if you could) would be a bad pattern. `UITableViewCell`s are designed to be created and modified solely in the `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath` datasource method, where framework automatically asks you what to do with cells that are about to be displayed.

The whole idea behind reusability is that the system takes care of the view for you, and all you need to do is take care of your datasource and instruct the system, using the model, how to render cells, in its allocated datasource method.

This paradigm would be defeated if we started accessing cells manually and modifying them.